# listview link to innerpage in jquery-mobile

Tags: listview, jquery-mobile

I have problem in jquery mobile's listview.

page has a few of "li" list.

```
<script>
    $("li").livequery("click", function(){
        $.mobile.changePage("#detailPage");
    });
</script>
....
....
<div data-role="page" id="home">
    <div data-role="content">
        <ul id="list" data-role="listview" data-filter="true">
            <li>
                <a href="#>
                    <h3>AAA</h3>
                    <p>AAA is...<p>
                    <p>$25.00</p>
                </a>
            </li>
            ....
            ....
            ....
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<div data-role="page" id="detailPage">
    ....
</div>
```

If I clicked a "li", it linked innerpage(detailPage)

but when I clicked "li",

**move to top of page** before linked innerpage

I don't want to that.

how do that.

please help me.

ps.I'm sorry, my english is not good.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe

> `$.mobile.silentScroll` (method) Scroll to a particular Y position
>   without triggering scroll event listeners. · Arguments: yPos (number,
>   defaults to 0). Pass any number to scroll to that Y location.

**Examples:**

```
//scroll to Y 100px             
$.mobile.silentScroll(100);
```

- http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0/docs/api/methods.html